Do Protestants believe that acceptance of their canon is an essential matter of faith?
Do any Protestant Christian movements/denominations believe that acceptance of the 39 book 'Old Testament/27 book 'New Testament', and only those 66 books as scripture is an essential doctrine of faith? Do any Protestant denominations require such a declaration? Why or why not?
For instance, is there a theological problem in Protestantism if a clergy member/lay person sincerely believed the academic consensus that the Second Epistle of Peter was not scripture? Or would protestants believe there a problem if the same person sincerely believes that 1/2 Maccabees are scripture?

My assumption here is that th reason why the 2nd Epistle Peter is largely considered not cananonical because in it Peter verifies the literal account of the Genesis flood and destruction of Sodom and gomorah (which are anti evolutionary)? For anyone worried about that, read Christs own statements about the Flood in Matthew 24 and Luke 17! If the incarnate God talks about the flood whilst ministering here on earth, and the apostle Peter also references it, theistic evolution has a big problem. I'll bet that is the real reason why...its an attempt at discrediting the YEC flood and creationism.

@adam that is one possibility, however, I heard somewhere (I would need to check my book references) that the reason for the rejection of 2nd Peter has to do with at least the difference in writing style than 1st Peter.

@Cork88 that is the justification used, but it's a fairly specious argument. It's possible and even probable that Peter used an amanuensis (as we know Paul did) since it's rather likely that he didn't have perfect literary Greek. The difference in style reflects a difference between his collaborators. Specifically, Sylvanus in 1 Peter 5:12 may be a reference to his amanuensis, while 2 Peter he wrote either with someone else or on his own.

@user111403 I agree, I never said an amanuensis was not used, however I just wanted to make a point for why some critical scholars make that assertion.  (In the event that nobody has heard this info before).  Good points though.

I dunno why anyone would really reject it... it is approved by every ancient canon and council... must be a modern protestant thing. Look forward to seeing someone answer.

@AviAvraham Who does state that Second Epistle of Peter does not belong to the canonical scripture? The Wikipedia article you link only talks about the authorship. At least in catholic theology there is no direct connection of authorship and canonical status; I don't know protestant views on this.

@adam I do not think that's the reason for doubting it, as the same reasoning would lead to one doubting Luke and Romans etc. I think the reasons are largely textual/circumstantial.

I used 2 Peter as an example, nothing more. The point of the question isn’t about that letter

All Sola Scriptura types obviously consider the canon to be extremely important (!), but they do not consider accepting the canon to be a prerequisite of salvation, because the canon itself does not list it as a prerequisite. :) Even those without Sola Scriptura are going to have the same take, provided they themselves believe the canon.

The last bit of the question is interesting. Is rejection of other books such as 'apocryphal' Christian texts a requirement?

There are lots of "theological problems" that aren't "essential matters of faith"! So your hypothetical example is not an actual example of what you're asking about.

For some time Martin Luther and many Lutherans had a canon (Luther’s Cannon) that put Hebrews, James, Jude, and Revelation in the category of "disputed books”.
It is easy to see James and Revelation as difficult for Luther to accept. James, when biased by how it was so thoroughly taught by Papal traditions, deeply conflicted with protestant faith.  It was not until after Luther died that good commentaries arose, which through careful analysis of the language of James showed there was no conflict and James is not preaching works as Luther felt it was.  For Revelation, it is also easy to understand his suspicions as nobody is confident on what it's really saying. I think Luther would have changed his mind if he were alive years after he died.
The moral of the story is that someone with great faith in scripture can doubt part of the cannon if they don't understand those books.  It is faith in Christ that saved, not faith in a defined cannon of scripture.  It is also not necessary, to be a strong Christian, to have read every book of the bible.  Abraham did not read a lot of it.

To be fair, even the ancient church had serious problems with revelations. It is too easy to misunderstand. It's on the edge of being a box of "instant heresy" :) (just add personal interpretation)

@Wyrsa - I think I have revolved around temporarily believing  literally every contradictory view of the book, so I wont judge ;) I am not proposing it be excluded as it makes a perfect ending, only saying my confidence of my understanding is low. haha

Ah mike, that is why I like the Orthodox church... they teach us to start from the position of "oh we know nothing" like a child curiously asking their parent how butterflys can fly. I do enjoy the various heresies from that book as nice fiction. Movies like the omega code are christian high fantasy :)

This is a really useful historical answer, just curious about the ending - are you calling Abraham a Christian?

@AviAvraham It doesn't seem appropriate to call Abraham a "Christian", as he lived some time before Christ (though see John 8:58), but pretty much any Christian would consider him to be a true believer and to be saved.

Having said that, Abraham is also a bad example for the question. Abraham didn't have access to parts of the Bible, in fact he most likely had none of it (on the other hand, he had direct revelation from God). There's a big difference between not having access and explicitly, intentionally rejecting.

@AviAvraham - My meaning  about Abraham is  simply that faith is not dependant on a complete set of biblical texts.

@Mike Given that the books of the New Testament were written hundreds of years after the church was founded, it seems that your assertion is easily shown to be true.

@JimmyJames "the books of the NT were written hundreds of years after the church was founded" - care to expand on that? Even skeptical scholars don't place any books later than the early 2nd century, so unless you're using "the founding of the church" in a non-standard way, this is easily disproved (although your statement can be weakened and the point still stands).

@user111403 How many years are there in a century?

@JimmyJames 100. "Hundreds" implies more than one, so minimum 200, which takes us into the 3rd century. In fact, if we take the traditional founding of the church at Pentecost, roughly AD 30, then critical estimates put even the latest books within about a century, and the majority earlier. Hence the question.

@user111403 If we are quibbling about the length of time, I'm not a biblical scholar, I was just recalling from memory what I thought I understood, but my recollection could be flawed. Things like this note about Thessalonians 2 might be what I was thinking of: "But some of the language and theology point to a much later date". In any event, the larger point is that I think it is strange to claim that e.g., Paul did not have true faith due to not having read all the books in the canon.

@JimmyJames even if you accept the arguments, "much later" still means late 1st or early 2nd. But yeah, your point is valid even if the time gap is shorter (as I said in my first comment). I'll note that if I was playing devil's advocate, I'd say that Paul had access to other sources of revelation (directly and through prophets) which makes this an apples and oranges comparison.

A Christian is a follower of Christ. How can one claim Abraham wasnt Christian if he recieved direct revelation from the preincarnate Christ? Christianity is only a name, the fundamental beliefs havent changed. What Christ was called before the incarnation doesn't change anything. Christ said whilst on earth, "if you have seen me, you have seen the father" ...ie we are a mirror image of each other. That includes philosphical values does it not?


OP:  Do any Protestant Christian movements/denominations believe that acceptance of the 39 book 'Old Testament/27 book 'New Testament' as scripture is an essential doctrine of faith?

Yes, this belief is essential to doctrines of faith.
Lutheran

The canonical Scriptures of the Old and New Testaments are the Word of God. Inspired by God's Spirit speaking through their authors, they record and announce God's revelation centering in Jesus Christ. Through them God's Spirit speaks to us to create and sustain Christian faith and fellowship for service in the world.
We believe, teach, and accept the canonical Scriptures of the Old and New Testaments as the inspired Word of God and the sole authoritative source and norm of our proclamation, faith, and life.


About the BIBLE
Everything we believe as Lutheran Christians comes from the Bible, God's message of love and hope for all people. The Bible is the written Word of God, handed down to us in order to point us to the truth that we are saved from our sin and
eternal death by the life, death, and resurrection of Jesus Christ. We believe that the Bible is completely reliable and with no errors or contradictions. In it we learn everything we need to know about God's love and His gifts to us.
“All scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness.” (2Timothy
3:16) NIV

Baptist

We believe that the 66 books of the Bible are God’s inspired revelation to man. They are the very word of God, without error, completely authoritative, essential, sufficient, and trustworthy, and constitute the only infallible rule for truth and life. It is our constant privilege to read, study, teach, obey, and model God’s word in order to be truthful and loving ambassadors for Christ to our world. -Source-

Anglican

Anglicans consider the Bible to be fundamental to life as a Christian and believe that "the Scriptures contain all things necessary for salvation". -source-


VI. Of the Sufficiency of the holy Scriptures for salvation


Holy Scripture containeth all things necessary to salvation: so that whatsoever is not read therein, nor may be proved thereby, is not to be required of any man, that it should be believed as an article of the Faith, or be thought requisite or necessary to salvation. In the name of the holy Scripture we do understand those Canonical Books of the Old and New Testament, of whose authority was never any doubt in the Church.


Of the Names and Number of the Canonical Books


Genesis
Exodus
Leviticus
Numbers
Deuteronomy
Joshua
Judges
Ruth
The First Book of Samuel
The Second Book of Samuel
The First Book of Kings
The Second Book of Kings
The First Book of Chronicles
The Second Book of Chronicles
The First Book of Esdras
The Second Book of Esdras
The Book of Esther
The Book of Job
The Psalms
The Proverbs
Ecclesiastes or Preacher
Cantica, or Songs of Solomon
Four Prophets the greater
Twelve Prophets the less


And the other Books (as Hierome saith) the Church doth read for example of life and instruction of manners; but yet doth it not apply them to establish any doctrine; such are these following:


The Third Book of Esdras
The Fourth Book of Esdras
The Book of Tobias
The Book of Judith
The rest of the Book of Esther
The Book of Wisdom
Jesus the Son of Sirach
Baruch the Prophet
The Song of the Three Children
The Story of Susanna
Of Bel and the Dragon
The Prayer of Manasses
The First Book of Maccabees
The Second Book of Maccabees


All the Books of the New Testament, as they are commonly received, we do receive, and account them Canonical.

Methodist

Article V — Of the Sufficiency of the Holy Scriptures for Salvation
The Holy Scripture containeth all things necessary to salvation; so that whatsoever is not read therein, nor may be proved thereby, is not to be required of any man that it should be believed as an article of faith, or be thought requisite or necessary to salvation. In the name of the Holy Scripture we do understand those canonical books of the Old and New Testament of whose authority was never any doubt in the church. The names of the canonical books are:


Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, Deuteronomy, Joshua, Judges, Ruth, The First Book of Samuel, The Second Book of Samuel, The First Book of Kings, The Second Book of Kings, The First Book of Chronicles, The Second Book of Chronicles, The Book of Ezra, The Book of Nehemiah, The Book of Esther, The Book of Job, The Psalms, The Proverbs, Ecclesiastes or the Preacher, Cantica or Songs of Solomon, Four Prophets the Greater, Twelve Prophets the Less.


All the books of the New Testament, as they are commonly received, we do receive and account canonical.

Evangelical

We believe the Bible to be the inspired, the only infallible, authoritative Word of God. -Source-

Each of these groups affirm the 66 book of Scripture with 39 of the OT and 27 of the NT.
The alternative to accepting these specific books of the Bible is to be subject to later non-authoritative additions of books, Traditions, prophets, and traditions as if on par with Scripture.
EDIT OF OP >is there a theological problem in Protestantism if a clergy member/lay person sincerely believed the academic consensus that the Second Epistle of Peter was not scripture?
There are all sorts of lay persons in all sorts of religions who have opinions about all sorts of things.  Must you have been present when Peter penned 2nd Peter in order to have faith in what has been handed down as Scripture for some 2,000 years?  No.  It simply calls for more information.

[to those who] say in reply that things confirmed by ancient usage cannot be changed, error is manifestly ancient; but truth which reproves it is ever more ancient still.
Selected Epistles of Gregory the Great, Book IX, Epistle CXXVII, From S. Columbanus to Pope Gregory

In this case, I'll stick with Columbanus.

OP Or would protestants believe there a problem if the same person sincerely believes that 1/2 Maccabees are scripture?

Again, that person simply does not understand why the 39 books of the OT are the OT.  It is because of the Hebrew requirement of a valid prophetic line when it was written and included.  Maccabees in fact asserts the same thing; that is, Maccabees is not included in/as Scripture because it was written during the "silent period" that Protestants later termed from Malachi to the Baptist's time.
The primary idea behind the Reformation on which Protestants built was the sufficiency of Scripture on all things salvific.  You didn't need self-appointed leaders, you didn't need pious traditions, you didn't need books written post apostolic times in order to be saved.
At the same time, the question of which Scripture arose.  It is those books handed down as divine, written between the bookends of the first and last apostles to die, the Sons of Thunder.
EDIT:  To explain to the detractors about the quotes answering the OP, I'm not going to highlight where each quote says the same thing; that is, the very specific 66 books of the Bible contain all that is necessary for salvation.  These quotes, these Protestants, all specifically exclude Traditions, Popes, Prophets, and Books that come after the time when the NT was written.  They all do this because they all understand that the Bible is the very breath of God Almighty revealing Himself to mankind.  They all understand that though someone may claim something, it may be pious, but it has no authority, no merit, no truth apart from Scripture.  And they further claim the very specific books of Scripture.

This is a really well researched answer. I updated the question to include if protestant denominations require acceptance of only the 66 book canon

None of these teach that accepting the exact same canon is essential for faith or salvation.

@curiousdannii   Hmmm, are you Catholic, JW, LDS, or something else because the groups in my answer do believe the 66 book canon is essential for faith and salvation.  Did you actually read the answer?  Read them again and be specific that they don't teach what you are asserting without proof.  Matter of fact, get each specific citation from each group that says what you believe about them.

@AviAvraham thank you.  I've updated my answer as well.

I will expand the statement about the Anglican position. Article VI of the 39 Articles of Religion declares the sufficiency of the scriptures for faith, and as part of this declaration names the books identified as scripture. But this is about not going outside that list, rather than enforcing the reading of all of them. The maximum, not the minimum.

@SLM None of your quotes say it is essential for Christians to agree about the canon. None of them say that your salvation depends on the canon you accept.

@curiousdannii  I see.  You believe one may read Webster's Dictionary and be saved.  All things salvific are in the New York Post or CCC or etc.  Good luck with that.

@SLM Huh? I didn't say anything like that. Your quotes teach all the standard Protestant doctrines of scripture, but needing to agree on the canon is not one of them. Obviously you wouldn't be able to be ordained into one of these denominations if you disagreed on the canon, but that doesn't mean agreement of canon is an "essential matter of faith".

@SLM I think you're not quite getting the point. Yes, all these denominations agree on the canon, and they all agree that it's important. And probably none of them believe that you can be saved without Scripture. But what they don't teach is that you lose your salvation if you don't believe that, say, Esther is inspired, or if you believe that 2 Ezra is. Or if they do teach that, the texts you cited don't say so. The fact is that neglecting some part of Scripture is a serious mistake, but the other 65 books contain enough of the gospel to be saved. Your sarcasm is out of line.
